# translating list comprehensions to definitions using map and concat

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

From *Thinking Functionally with Haskell*, pg 67:

```
[...] list comprehensions are translated into equivalent definitions in
terms of map and concat. The translation rules are:

[e | True]       = [e] 
[e | q]          = [e | q, True] 
[e | b, Q]       = if b then [e | Q] else [] 
[e | p <- xs, Q] = let ok p = [e | Q]
                       ok _ = []
                   in concat (map ok xs)
```

The author nowhere defines e, q, Q, or b. I take it that the first means "expression," but I've never seen the others before. Could someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This translation comes straight out of the official [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11), which has this additional sentence:

> where `e` ranges over expressions, `p` over patterns, `l` over list-valued expressions, `b` over boolean expressions, `decls` over declaration lists, `q` over qualifiers, and `Q` over sequences of qualifiers. `ok` is a fresh variable. The function `concatMap`, and boolean value `True`, are defined in the `Prelude`.

If you wonder what any of those terms means, the Report has further details.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that:

- e is any expression, as you say
- q is any expression with type `Bool`
- b is also any expression with type `Bool` (this seems a bit strange, though, perhaps I'm wrong...)
- p is any pattern. For example, `Right x`, `Just _`, `x@(y,z)`
- Q is a bunch of list comprehension elements separated by commas. By "list comprehension element" I mean either guards (i.e. expressions of type `Bool`) or pattern matches, e.g `x <- xs`, `Right x <- xs`.